# WPF loading a BitmapImage into an image programatically

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying to load an image into an `Image` control in a WPF application.

I need to set the Input in one function, and bind it to the `Image` in another.

This works:

```
var b = new Binding { Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFromString("D:/data/TestPattern.jpg") };
CameraFrame.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, b);
```

But this does not:

```
BitmapImage bSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri("D:/data/TestPattern.jpg"));
var b = new Binding { Source = (ImageSource)new ImageSourceConverter().ConvertFrom(bSource) };

CameraFrame.SetBinding(Image.SourceProperty, b);
```

Why is this? Am I missing something in the `ConvertFrom` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply set the `Source` property to a `BitmapImage`?

```
CameraFrame.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("D:/data/TestPattern.jpg"));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I am actually setting the `BitmapImage` in another thread, and calling an opencv dll. So I cannot use the file string.

Comment: So? My main point is; why do you try to create a binding instead of simply setting the ImageSource property to an image?

Comment: You don't need to convert an BitmapImage to something else

Comment: I was under the impression that it would not update when the image does, if i do it that way. Am I wrong?

Comment: No difference. It will be updated whenever you set the Source property one way or another, i.e. whether the value is resolved using a binding or set directly.

Comment: I see. thanks! I am trying your suggestion above, and the image does not display

Comment: Note that it makes no sense to call SetValue. Just assign a value to the Source property. It's straightforward and also type-safe.